Qatar visa for Tajik citizen
I'm looking for tickets from NYC to Moscow at the end of June. I'm a citizen of Tajikistan.
I found tickets NYC - Istanbul - Tashkent - Moscow. But in this case, I need a Turkish visa.
There is another option NYC - Doha (Qatar) - Moscow.
The question arises: do I need a Qatari visa in this case?
Thank you!
